# Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful

Tags: jquery, cordova, xmlhttprequest, cors, ios10

Am trying to call CORS Rest API but am getting this error:

> Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful

This happens on my cordova apps after upgrading to iOS10, before that it used to work normally!

Here are the request/response headers, it does not complain about a specific header it only gives the above message!

[image: request/response headers]

Answer (score 0):

If you're still experiencing this issue, it appears to have been solved [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/70). The recommended solutions were:

- Implementing CORS server-side
- Using [Cordova native http plugin](https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http)

Answer (score 0):

just insert below code in app.js just above routes

``````
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'authtoken,content-type,application/json, text/plain, */*');
  if(req.method==='OPTIONS')
  {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, TRACE, PATCH');
      return res.status(200).json({});
  }
next()
})
// routes middleware
readdirSync("./routes").map((r) => app.use("/api", require("./routes/" + r)));



`````
``````